# Iframe.html Getting traffic in google Analytics But This i dont have in my code

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I would like to ask a question, my website is [Luxos.com](http://www.luxos.com), We dont have this page www.luxos.com/interface/iframe/iframe1.html in our root directory,

In google analytics we are getting visits to this page everyday about 200-1000, And bounce rate is 100%, average time is 0, We really dont understand why we are getting traffic from this page, almost 90% visitors are from china,

This is because of facebook ?? But for sharing we are using Sharethis Api widget, i checked very carefully from my whole website we dont have a single iframe code,

Please help me regarding this,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visitors look for `iframe1.html` but not found. Therefore, the bounce rate is 100%.

Comment: But; its should say then page  missing, why this page is active,

Comment: If we dont have any page like this why people are looking for this there nothing with this, yes afcourse our chiense website have this same file wwww.luxos.hk/interface/iframe/iframe1.html, but hosting server is different, domain is differnt nothing to with this,